# Frequency count of two date and time columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 114,209 data frame (df) with this 2 columns:

```
Date            Time 
2017-05-01     23H 0M 0S
2017-05-01     23H 0M 0S
2017-05-01     23H 30M 0S
2017-05-01     23H 30M 0S
2017-05-02     23H 0M 0S
2017-05-02     22H 0M 0S
2017-05-02     23H 0M 0S

> str(m)
'data.frame':   114209 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ DATAS         : Date, format: "2017-05-01" "2017-05-01" ...
 $ Time_Intervals:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ .Data : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ hour  : num  1 1 1 2 3 7 7 8 8 8 ...
  .. ..@ minute: num  0 0 0 30 0 30 30 30 30 30 ...
```

I need to count frequency of both columns and get the result in this format:

```
Date            Time         Freq
2017-05-01     23H 0M 0S       2
2017-05-01     23H 30M 0S      2
2017-05-02     23H 0M 0S       2
2017-05-02     22H 0M 0S       1
```

I think the problem is in the fact that my data is dates and hours.

I have tried several solutions for similar problems but nothing has worked.
-> `as.data.frame(table(df))` - the result is a table with all 0

```
> counts <- ddply(m, .(m$DATAS, m$Time_Intervals), nrow)
> names(counts) <- c("Datas", "Time", "Freq")
> counts
         Datas      Time Freq
1   2017-05-01  1H 0M 0S  125
2   2017-05-02    30M 0S  129
3   2017-05-03    30M 0S  117
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `plyr` is pretty dated, mostly replaced by `dplyr`. Try `dplyr::count(m)`.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica--
I have tried that solution but doesn't work. Probably because I can't install the package correctly in Rstudio.
`install.packages("dplyr", verbose=T)` Instead of "done" this message appears after a long waiting time
`1): succeeded 'C:/Users/DSSERR~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-36~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\dsserrano\Documents\R\R-3.6.2\library" C:\Users\DSSERR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpExbvzd/downloaded_packages/BH_1.72.0-2.tar.gz'
The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\dsserrano\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpExbvzd\downloaded_packages`

Comment: After experimenting with the code, I see that ddply is not able to group by class 'period'. You need to convert time to a different class: 'as.character' works or there are lots of other options if you don't want it to be a character.